# Div not showing on image hover

Tags: css, html, hover

I've got a div wrapped in another div and this div has to show up when hovered on the image. But the thing is that when an image is placed (img src) in that div container the div won't show anymore on hover.. I don't know how to fix this, and I don't understand why it does work for the other div.

This is my html code:

```
<!--- START [01] --->
<div class="f1">
    <img src="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/original/zdc1F5znCaBRZaqqDdwFakWUltE.jpg" width="139" height="200">
    <div class="f2"><b>Khumba</b><span class="yr"><b>(2013)</b></span>
        <br /> <span class="moreinfo"><a href="/">Watch trailer</a> // <a href="/coming-soon#hercules">more info</a></span> 
    </div>
    <div class="f3">
        <div class="half"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--- END [01] --->
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ffXX9/
(the heart icon won't show up on hover when an image is placed in that div..)

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what's not working. When I hover over the "Khumba" image, I get a little thing overlay with "Watch Trailer" and "More Info" links. Am I supposed to see something else?

Comment: Yes, you should see the heart icon (hover on the div where no image is placed)

Comment: I do see the heart icon so is there something that I'm missing? Also make sure to close your image tags with an `/>` at the end.

Comment: Do you see it when you hover on the image (the 'Khumba' image)?? Is this a browser thing again?

Comment: Nope I see what was going on and someone beat me to the answer:p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reposition the div

EXAMPLE http://jsfiddle.net/ffXX9/2/

```
<div class="f1">
    <div class="f3" title="bla">
        <div class="half"></div>
    </div>
     <img src="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/original/zdc1F5znCaBRZaqqDdwFakWUltE.jpg" width="139" height="200">
    <div class="f2">PPPOOOOPPP <span class="yr">(YEAR)</span> 
    </div>

</div>
```